# Does anyone know of any good software for SharePoint email filing

Tags: sharepoint, email

I am looking at trying to find a way of using SharPoint for filing company Emails (specifc ones anyway)
Does anybody have any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

You can Try out [Email Enabled List / Lib](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA100823071033.aspx) which allows you to send a email directly to Library

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box options:

- Uses standard/free functionality
- No automatic promotion of email properties (e.g. To, From, Subject, Date) from Outlook to SharePoint columns
- No way of user tagging or entering additional SharePoint column values during save
- Single email at a time

Option 1 - Save file manually as an .msg file from Outlook, then upload to SharePoint through SharePoint UI (2003/2007/2010)

Option 2 - Create a network location to your SharePoint site(s) then save to these locations using the Save As dialog in Outlook (2003/2007/2010) - for more details see http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1172-how-to-save-content-from-office-documents-into-sharepoint-2010/

Option 3 - Enable and configure incoming email for SharePoint lists/libraries (each list/library gets its own email address that users can send to). Emails are stored in .eml format not .msg.

Option 4 - Drag/Drop to File Explorer View of SharePoint Library (Note: Email Attributes and additional Column mapping is not captured)

Option 5 - Exchange Server /SharePoint Server connection (Server side driven, IT over head, no capture of custom metadata)

Commercial (3rd party) options:
A few commercial products are available in the market to help with integration between Outlook and SharePoint. (Note: I am associated with OnePlaceMail)

OnePlaceMail is one solution you are can download and evaluate for this need:
http://www.scinaptic.com/outlook-to-sharepoint-integration.html

Example functionality provided by OnePlaceMail:

- Drag and Drop emails from Outlook to SharePoint
- Capture email attributes such as To, CC, From, Subject, etc... and promote to SharePoint columns
- Allow the user to enter additional SharePoint Column information at the point of saving emails to SharePoint
- Email messages are stored in SharePoint in the native .msg format
- Send and save email to SharePoint in a single action
- Save email attachments to SharePoint
- Save Files from File Explorer into SharePoint
- Save Office documents (Word, Excel and PowerPoint) directly to SharePoint
- Access SharePoint from Microsoft Outlook
- Create end to end solutions using the OnePlaceMail API

Answer (score 1):

Not absolutely sure if I'm breaking any rules here, but I'd be lying if I didn't recommend our own product [Epona EmailFiler](http://www.epona.com/en/products/EmailFiler/Pages/Default.aspx) for exactly this purpose.

For storing email, you want a solution that integrates tightly into Outlook, because that is *what your users know*.

---

To keep this post politically correct I probably should list some of our competitors, mostly [Colligo Cotributor](http://www.colligo.com/products/sharepoint/contributor_add-in.asp) and [nSynergy myDocs](http://www.nsynergy.com/products/mydocs/Pages/About_myDocs.aspx), and lately a dozen other players.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13295/is-it-appropriate-to-mention-my-product-in-a-stackoverflow-answer for guidance. I think it's fair provided its a valid answer and you give disclosure.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and link, Alex! It's about time I started reading up a bit on the meta forums...